# Exo-Player 2.10.1 says SimpleCache(File cacheDir, CacheEvictor evictor) deprecated

Tags: android, kotlin, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I am using `ExoPlayer` to play videos from online server. So, for better to save more internet or data for replay video I'm just caching all videos to `Cache directory`. But problem its saying that deprecated `constructor` of `SimpleCache`.

See my code:

```
private var sDownloadCache: SimpleCache? = null

fun getInstance(mContext: Context): SimpleCache {
    val cacheEvictor = LeastRecentlyUsedCacheEvictor((100 * 1024 * 1024).toLong())

    if (sDownloadCache == null)
        sDownloadCache = SimpleCache(File(mContext.getCacheDir(), "media"),
                cacheEvictor)
    return sDownloadCache!!
}
```

In this code compiler is just warn me **constructor SimpleCache(File!, CacheEvictor!) is deprecated. Deprecated in Java**. So, after that I'm trying to find way in file of `SimpleCache.java` there is a way to use `SimpleCache` now is..

```
SimpleCache(File cacheDir, CacheEvictor evictor, DatabaseProvider databaseProvider)
```

And its new to me. So, my problem is how to use this new constructor instead of old deprecated one? Is there way to pass `DatabaseProvider`? If yes then how or from what?

I'm using `ExoPlayer` libraries:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.10.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.10.1'
```

And its because this version provides easy to create `ExoPlayerFactory` `instance` and `build ProgressiveMediaSource`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this:

```
        val evictor = LeastRecentlyUsedCacheEvictor((100 * 1024 * 1024).toLong())
        val databaseProvider: DatabaseProvider = StandaloneDatabaseProvider(mContext)

        simpleCache = SimpleCache(File(mContext.cacheDir, "media"), evictor, databaseProvider)
        

        val mediaSource = ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(
            simpleCache?.let {
                CacheDataSourceFactory(
                    mContext,
                    100 * 1024 * 1024, 10 * 1024 * 1024, playUri, it
                )
            }
        )
            .createMediaSource(playUri)

        exoPlayer?.prepare(mediaSource)
```

Comment: Good. Now android studio not showing that yellow line :)

Comment: 'ExoDatabaseProvider' is deprecated and you can replace it with StandaloneDatabaseProvider(mContext)